# How to fix "error processing purchase. [DF-PDP-3]" error in Android TV inapp purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-tv

**Getting below Error on Android TV:-**

"error processing purchase. [DF-PDP-3]" This bug we are getting into Android TV while making Inapp purchase.

This issue occurs only in Android TV, not in Android Mobile with same code implementation for InApp purchase.

**Steps to reproduce:-**

Our app is not yet published on Production, Its in Alpha release. When we try to make Inapp purchase with new Gmail account which is not added into sandbox, we are getting above error, but with same Gmail account login on Mobile it don't show this error. It opens add payment method screen like Add your credit card.

If we add same Gmail account into sandbox test user into Google play developer account then above error gets removed. So our Question is for Gmail user which are not in sandbox testers how we can purchase Inapp product from Android TV.

We are trying to Alpha release the application for Android Tv, but App gets rejected on Android Tv App review on Google Developer. But same App gets approved for Android Mobile. Rejection reason is above Error.

So, If anyone know details of this error. Why this occurs only in Android TV not in Android Mobile. If any solution to resolve this issue please suggest us.

[Error screenshot we are getting while making Inapp Purchase form Android TV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtqBH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding test accounts in the settings of the developer console in the [License Testing section](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#test-purchases-sandbox).